# JavaScript setInterval not decreasing variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, setinterval

```
<div id="rope" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg);-webkit-transition:all 1s;position:absolute;top:50px;left:50px;">

<div style="position:absolute;top:25px;left:25px;width:5px;background-color:#c3c3c3;height:100px;"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:15px;"><img src="http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20111028025351/cuttherope/images/1/1c/Candy.png" style="height:30px;"></div>

</div>

<script>
count = 25;
setInterval(function(){

document.getElementById("rope").style.webkitTransform="rotate("+count+"deg)";

count = count*-1;

count = count-1;

} ,'1000');
</script>
```

Test it out, there's an issue: it never decreases the amount that it rotated back and forth in.

Need help, because this should be easy to fix however setInterval always manages to stump me, especially dealing with adding to variables :\

I want it to rotate less, and less, each time... thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: `25*-1-1 == -26` `-26*-1-1 == 25`

Comment: So what? I thought that there should at least be a change in numbers, even if they're adding wrong @FabrícioMatté

Comment: What Fabricio is trying to say that after every second interval, the number returns to 25.

Comment: Oh yeah. Dang I'm retarded (no offense)... Sooo how would I detect whether the number is negative or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that count is bouncing between -26 and 25.

For each interval:

1. count = -count - 1 = -26.
2. count = -(-26) - 1 = 26 - 1 = 25.
3. count = -(25) - 1 = -26.
4. count = ...

So count will bouncing between these two values; -26 and 25.

As per your comment, implement this simply by an if-test (i.e. if (count < 0) {...}).

Comment: Okay... got it :) Sooo how would I detect whether the number is negative or not.

Comment: Alright got it. That makes sense, I'll do an if. :) if > 0 else

Answer (score 0):

Your `count = count*-1;` and `count = count-1;` will just repeat a pattern of -26 and 25.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution JS

```
count = 25;
intvar=setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("rope").style.webkitTransform = "rotate("+count+"deg)";

    count = count*-1;
    if(count>0)
    {
        count = count-4;// Change 4 to any small integer to keep the difference of angular travel(in degree) each time as small as possible and keep it big if you want a greater difference each time in the angular travel.
        if(count<0)
            clearInterval(intvar);
        console.log(count);
    }
} ,'1000');
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yXw4n/)**